# set path to from the root directory

Tags: php

How can I set path, for upload files, that always will start from the root directory?

```
$usersFiles = "???";
if (move_uploaded_file($files['file']['tmp_name'][$i], $usersFiles.$files['file']['name'][$i]))
```

Comment: `a folder in the root directory/`

Comment: note that for security and conflicts issues you better not save the file in its original name (use some random hash)

Answer (score 0):

You can always refer to the root folder by using slash:

```
$usersFiles = "/";
```

Comment: so, if my folder is "imageFile" that i should put: $usersFiles = "/imageFile"; ?

Comment: depending on the structure of your `$files` array, you may have to add another slash (`/`) at the end...